# Google Play Games achievement unlocked popup not showing

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm unlocking achievement using this simple method from developers docs:

```
Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(), "my_achievement_id");
```

Achievement unlocks, but no popup shows up. There is also no popup when logged in to Google Play Games - which is connected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add a view to the layouts you want to display achievements on like this:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/gps_popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

When you have your layout ready you neet to execute this inside your Activity or Fragment:

```
Games.setViewForPopups(getApiClient(), findViewById(R.id.gps_popup));
```

You have to be sure, that your GoogleApiClient is connected though, otherwise your app will crash.

Comment: Does the GoogleApiClient actually have to be connected? What if it's properly instantiated but not actually connected? I don't see why being connected should have any impact on setting a view.

Comment: The link to your blog article appears to be broken.

Answer (score 8):

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/gps_popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

This is the same in Jacek Kwiecień answer

```
GamesClient gamesClient = Games.getGamesClient(MainActivity.this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context));
gamesClient.setViewForPopups(findViewById(R.id.gps_popup));
```

This changed because setViewForPopups with 2 parameters is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

Jacek and user3782779 answers didn't work for me, I had to do the following:

```
GamesClient gamesClient = Games.getGamesClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this));
gamesClient.setViewForPopups(findViewById(android.R.id.content));
gamesClient.setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I have solved it by **adding icon to the achievement**. I am not kidding, it is really strange but it started to work after that. Please note that I am talking about **not published** project, I was just testing my app and wondering what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY `view` that worked for my case of having multiple activities was:

```
activity.window.decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

I had the same problem with the achievement popup. The "Welcome Back" popup was showing correctly by just using my own View, but once I started opening other screens where I wanted to show the achievement unlocked popup, it was not working. The only thing that ended up working was using the `content` view from the decorView

```
val gamesClient = Games.getGamesClient(activity, googleSignInAccount)
gamesClient.setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP or Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
gamesClient.setViewForPopups(activity.window.decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.content))
```

You can call this code from any new activity you open and the pop-up will show up there as soon as you unlock your achievements.