# libgdx: unlocked Achievement pop-up not shown

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games

Some users in this site asked my question like this [unlocked-popup-not-showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474718/google-play-games-achievement-unlocked-popup-not-showing)  and [Unlocked Achievement Popup not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748866/google-play-game-service-unlocked-achievement-popup-not-shown?lq=1) but doesn't work for me I don't know what is wrong in my code?

**Firstly** to clear my question for all users. My Question is How can I show a pop-up notification for unlocked `Achievement`? like this image:

[image]

**Secondly** my android class `MainActivity` implements the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements IGoogleServices, GameHelperListener {
     private GameHelper _gameHelper;
.......
```

which `IGoogleServices` interface is:

```
public interface IGoogleServices {
    .....
    public boolean isSignedIn();
    public void unlockAchievement(String achievementId);
    public void showAchievements();
}
```

**Thirdly** the code in `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    // Create the GameHelper.
    _gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
    _gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);

    _gameHelper.setup(this);

    initialize(new MyGdxGame(this, this), config);
}
```

**Fourthly** the implementaion methods:

```
@Override
public void unlockAchievement(String achievementId) {
    if (isSignedIn()) {
        Games.Achievements.unlock(_gameHelper.getApiClient(), achievementId);
    }
}
```

**Fifthly** I threw the `IGoogleServices` interface into `MyGdxGame` game:

```
public MyGdxGame(IGoogleServices googleServices) {
    this.googleServices = googleServices;
}
```

**Finally** I created `Image` as button to unlock the first achievement:

```
final Image iAch1 = new Image(ach1);
iAch1.addListener(new InputListener() {
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        return true;
    }
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        googleServices.unlockAchievement("CgkIzZ.......");
    }
});
stage.addActor(iAch1);
```

So far everything is okay and the `Achievements` unlocked **BUT** without pop-up
notifications as shown in previous image. How can I achieve that?

Comment: At a glance things looks right.  Perhaps your emulator does not have all the required things to display it?  Try a different emulator with google libraries or on a real device