# Google Play Achievements Popup does not show up

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am quite new with the Google-Play library and could not find out, why I do not get a message when unlocking an achievement in my application.

This is the code I use at the moment

```
final AppCompatActivity activity = this;

        Games.getGamesClient(this, acc).setViewForPopups(findViewById(R.id.popupBar)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                AchievementsClient aClient = Games.getAchievementsClient(activity, acc);
                aClient.unlock(getString(R.string.achievement_game_started));
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Got Achievement", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

this code is used inside the `onActivityResult` function, which is called after

```
GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

I also tried to unlock an achievement with a manual button click afterwards, but I still get no Popup.
The layout file for `R.id.popupBar` is inside `layouts` and looks like the following:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/popupBar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've been checking similar questions here in Stack Overflow and found [this same problem as you have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474718/google-play-games-achievement-unlocked-popup-not-showing). Maybe you can follow how they code the `setViewForPopups`. Also, be noted that `viewForPopups` cannot be null. You can check it out [here](http://androiddoc.qiniudn.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html#setViewForPopups(android.view.View)). And make sure that your `GoogleApiClient` is connected.

Comment: Ah, found the misstake. `findViewById` returned a nullpointer indeed. I have missunderstood the answer in the link and added a new xml-File with a Fragment-Layout instead of adding it to the existing layout-file and then inflated the new view...
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please make sure to post your answer for future reference.